# Duda sobre las Funciones en Javascript

Tags: javascript, web, function

Estoy empezando a aprender la sintaxis de Javascript y me surgió una duda en las Funciones. He visto que hay dos formas de definir una funcion, que pueden ser estas:

```
function mostrarEdad (edad) {
    return edad;
}
```

o también

```
mostrarEdad = function(edad) {
    return edad;
}
```

Y mi duda es mas que nada sobre la segunda forma, ya que a una variable le estamos asignando una función, y he visto que tambien le ponen ya sea `var`, `let` y `const` y aquí surge mi duda, tengo claro que es lo que hace tanto el `var` como el `let` y `const` en **variables**, pero no entiendo como afecta a una funcion.

A las variables le veo lógica el especificar su scope, ya que si por ejemplo definimos una variable `let edad` dentro de un `for`, solo podremos acceder a esa variable en el `for`. Pero en las funciones no las definimos dentro de ninguna otra estructura, entonces no le encuentro sentido, asi como tampoco le veo sentido que sean constantes...

Más exactamente mi duda es que diferencias hay entre poner esto

```
const mostrarEdad = function(edad) {
    return edad;
}
```

o poner

```
let mostrarEdad = function(edad) {
    return edad;
}
```

u poner

```
var mostrarEdad = function(edad) {
    return edad;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Con relación especifica tu pregunta o duda:

**CONST:** Es una constante la cual NO cambiara su valor en ningún momento en el futuro.

**VAR:** Es una variable que SI puede cambiar su valor y su scope es local.

**LET:** Es una variable que también podrá cambiar su valor, pero solo vivirá(Funcionara) en el bloque donde fue declarada.

Ahora bien, en el caso de tu ejemplo, la diferencia clave entre estas metodologías radica en la "elevación", que toma una variable definida hacia el final de un scope y te permite acceder a ella como si estuviera definida al principio del scope.

Si aún no te queda claro, te dejo este enlace:
[La diferencia entre function, vary let/ const.](https://medium.com/@Charles_Stover/the-difference-between-function-var-and-let-const-8175e013776)